# Need to find/download the absolute latest update to Microsoft Exchange 2000 Server

Tags: exchange

Per [kb158530](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158530) its post-SP3 6.0.6620.7 August 2008, however I cannot find. Latest I found was [6603.1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870540)

Comment: Your question inspires my sincere condolences and incredible pity.  May God have mercy on your soul and deliver you from this hell forthwith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Security Update for Exchange 2000 Server (KB959897)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10673) is listed as version 6.0.6620.9. You should already have [Update Rollup for Exchange 2000 (KB870540)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17070) installed before applying it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892986) to 6.0.6617.50.  That's the newest build I can find on the download site.  Given that Exchange 2000 is probably pretty close to falling out of support you really should look at upgrading to something made in the last 10 years.

Comment: Totally agree. I just don't think they will front the money & the response is why fix whats not broken (yet anyway). Any suggesting on a open-source alternative to Exchange?

Comment: I'm the wrong guy to ask about open-source.  I'd put together something that shows the costs of upgrading vs. the costs of doing nothing, including a failure or two (include the cost of you searching for out of band updates), etc.